# User Specified CUSTOM Work item- with particular group members as drop down list in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-process-template

User Specified  CUSTOM Work item- with particular group members as drop down list in TFS 2015, In VS2015, its working but in TFS 2015 WebPortal its not showing. Showing all the members list added rules:

```
<FIELD name="Dev Approver" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.DevApprover" type="String" reportable="dimension">
   <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
    <VALIDUSER group="[global]\Dev Approver" />
    <ALLOWEDVALUES for="[global]\Dev Approver" expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="[global]\Dev Approver" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
 </FIELD>
```

its working in VS2015, but in TFS 2015 Web Portal it is not showing the above group list rather showing all like cache users list recently used members list >

Comment: Yeah, it shows the MRU, but will validate on save. Not sure you'll be able to fix that. I suggest filing a bug on Connect. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Answer (score 1):

VALIDUSER adds all users in the project. Remove that tag to show just the members of the other team. The "for" on that tag only restricts members of that group from using that set of values.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your scenario. It's a default behavior. On Web Access, the drop down only shows the recently used members list or just Search option. But if you select someone not in list `[global]\Dev Approver`, you'll get validation error message like the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the ans, could you please specify me any MSDN article on this behaviour